# R: gWidgets: gText: add a search/find function

Tags: r

I'd like to ask if there is a way of adding a search/find function in gtext gwidget.

```
x <- c(1, 2)
y <- c(3, 4)
z <- c(5, 6)
df <- data.frame(x, y, z)
df.co <- capture.output(df) # get df as text
str.split <- strsplit(df.co, "\\s+") # split every line in its components
w1 <- gwindow()
gt1 <- gtext(container=w1)
insert(gt1, df.co)
```

Comment: How does your question relate to the code you provide? You mention a search/find function but don't say what it is supposed to do or what behavior it should have.

Comment: What have you tried in terms of the search/find function? What do you want it to do when it finds something? Give the location of the match? Highlight the match? Tell you whether there is a match? There's no mechanism for highlighting text in a `gtext`, but you could probably modify the text to add big markers where the match was.